# Slack create a confirmation for slash command

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

Is there any way to create a slash command with a confirmation so that each time user uses this slash command, instead of evoking the url all the time, it pops a confirmation? ex. "Are you sure?" something like that?

For example, let's say I have a slash command that sends a POST request to AWS API Gateway and evoke some AWS Lambda Function. I want to add a confirm to this slash command before sending POST request immediately

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail, and give examples of the slash command

Answer (score 4):

Although I am not totally sue I fully understand your issue, you can implement a confirmation workflow using Interactive Messages in Slack. That currently includes Buttons (e.g. A Yes  and a no button) and menus.

Please consult the excellent [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons) about Message Buttons on Slack for details.